# Writing a flat file, permission denied

Tags: informatica

I have got this issue :

```
WRT_8004          
Writer initialization failed [Error opening session output file [/*/diff_zipcode1.out] [error=Permission denied]]. 
Writer terminating.
```

The user for informatica has the right to write in this specific folder (I tried a touch it directly and it worked) but I  still get this error.
The only way for this workflow to work is to set the writing permission to everyone...
So I was wondering if informatica uses another user than the one who launchs the informatica server like my user on informatica ? And if this is the case how can I set the properties right to write on my folder.

Answer to my situation : I change the settings of the user of informatica after  I launched the informatica server so the modification wasn't really done for informatica point of view. To fix this problem, I only had to reboot the informatica server.

Answer (score 1):

Informatica will use whichever user has logged in to Power Center to create the file.
If you do not want to set full permissions to your folder, it would be best if you add the user into a group and provide write permissions to groups only.